# FileDocument with UIManagedDocument/core data

Tags: core-data, swiftui, uimanageddocument

When using SwiftUI to create a document based app, the default document type is to subclass `FileDocument`.

All examples lead to simple value types to be used in this document type.

I'm looking to create a `UIManagedDocument` in SwiftUI but there doesn't seem to be any mention of using `FileDocument` with core data. I noticed a `ReferenceFileDocument` but this leads to no examples either...

Has anyone had any experience of using either SwiftUI document type for core data based documents?

Comment: Same issue here... I have a working `ReferenceFileDocument` (you have to use/connect the `UndoManager` to make it save), but don't know how to make it work with `UIManagedDocument`

Answer (score 11):

After some more months, I came across this question once again.
Since my last comment on September 18th, I've worked myself on solving the puzzle of building a SwiftUI document-based app using Core Data.

Looking more in-depth I learned that the `UIManagedDocument` (respectively its parent `UIDocument`) infrastructure is really close/similar to what SwiftUI tries to implement. SwiftUI even uses `UIDocument` in the background to do "its magic". `UIDocument` and `UIManagedDocument` are simply some more archaic remnants of times where Objective-C was the dominant language. There was no Swift and there were no value-types.

In general I can give you the following tips to solve your challenge using Core Data within a `UIManagedDocument`:

- first of all, if you want to use Core Data, you will have to use a package/bundle based document format. This means your `UTType` will have to conform to `.package` (=`com.apple.package` in your Info.plist file). You won't be able to make Core Data work with only a plain file document.

```swift
extension UTType {
    static var exampleDocument: UTType {
        UTType(exportedAs: "com.example.mydocument", conformingTo: .package)
    }
}
```

- use a `ReferenceFileDocument` based class to build a wrapper document for your `UIManagedDocument`. This is necessary because you will have to know about the time when the object is released. In `deinit` you will have to call `managedDocument.close()` to ensure the `UIManagedDocument` is properly closed and no data is lost.
- the required function `init(configuration:)` is going to be called when an existing document is opened. Sadly, it is of no use when working with `UIManagedDocument` because we have only access to the `FileWrapper` of the document and not the `URL`. But the `URL` is what you need to initialize the `UIManagedDocument`.
- the required function `snapshot(contentType:)` and `fileWrappper(snapshot:, configuration:)` is only used to create a new empty document. (This is because we won't use the SwiftUI integrated `UndoManager` but the one from `UIManagedDocument` respectively Core Datas `NSManagedObjectContext`.) Therefore it is not relevant what your type for `Snapshot` is. You can use a `Date` or `Int` because the snapshot taken with the first function is not what you are going to write in the second function.
- The `fileWrappper(snapshot:, configuration:)` function should return the file structure of an empty `UIManagedDocument`. This means, it should contain a directory `StoreContent` and an empty file with the filename of the persistent store (default is `persistentStore`) as in the screenshot below.
  [image: Screenshot of package content]
  The `persistentStore-shm` and `persistentStore-wal` files are going to be created automatically when Core Data is starting up, so we do not have to create them in advance.
  I am using the following expression to create the `FileWrapper` representing the document:  (`MyManagedDocument` is my `UIManagedDocument` subclass)

```swift
FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [
    "StoreContent" : FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [
        MyManagedDocument.persistentStoreName : FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: Data())
    ])
])
```

- above steps allow us to create an empty document. But it still cannot be connected to our `UIManagedDocument` subclass, because we have no idea where the document (represented by the `FileWrapper` we have created) is located. Luckily SwiftUI is passing us the `URL` of the currently opened document in the `ReferenceFileDocumentConfiguration` which is accessible in the `DocumentGroup` content closure. The property `fileURL` can then be used to finally create and open our `UIManagedDocument` instance from the wrapper. I'm doing this as follows: (`file.document` is an instance of our `ReferenceFileDocument` class)

```swift
DocumentGroup(newDocument: { DemoDocument() }) { file in
    ContentView()
        .onAppear {
            if let url = file.fileURL {
                file.document.open(fileURL: url)
            }
        }
}
```

- in my `open(fileURL:)` method, I then instantiate the `UIManagedDocument` subclass and call `open` to properly initialize it.
- With above steps you will be able to display your document and access its `managedObjectContext` in a view similar to this: (`DocumentView` is a regular SwiftUI view using for example `@FetchRequest` to query data)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var document: DemoDocument

    var body: some View {
        if let managedDocument = document.managedDocument {
            DocumentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedDocument.managedObjectContext)
        } else {
            ProgressView("Loading")
        }
    }
}
```

But you will soon encounter some issues/crashes:

1. You see the app freeze when a document is opened. It seems as if `UIManagedDocument` `open` or `close` won't finish/return.
   This is due to some deadlock. (You might remember, that I initially told you that SwiftUI is using `UIDocument` behind the scene? This is probably the cause of the deadlock: we are running already some `open` while we try to execute another `open` command.
   **Workaround:** run all calls to `open` and `close` on a background queue.
2. Your app crashes when you try to open another document after having previously closed one. You might see errors as:

```
warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Item' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
warning:     'Item' (0x6000023c4420) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600003781220) claims 'Item'.
warning:     'Item' (0x6000023ecb00) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600003787930) claims 'Item'.
error: +[Item entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
```

After having debugged this for some hours, I learned that the `NSManagedObjectModel` (instantiated by our `UIManagedDocument`) is not released between closing a document and opening another. (Which, by good reason, is not necessary as we would use the same model anyway for the next file we open). The solution I found to this problem was to override the `managedObjectModel` variable for my `UIManagedDocument` subclass and return the `NSManagedObjectModel` which I'm loading "manually" from my apps bundle. I suppose there are nicer ways to do this, but here is the code I'm using:

```swift
class MyManagedDocument: UIManagedDocument {

    // We fetch the ManagedObjectModel only once and cache it statically
    private static let managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        guard let url = Bundle(for: MyManagedDocument.self).url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Model.xcdatamodeld not found in bundle")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Model.xcdatamodeld not load from bundle")
        }
        return mom
    }()


    // Make sure to use always the same instance of the model, otherwise we get crashes when opening another document
    override var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
         Self.managedObjectModel
    }
}
```

So this answer has become really lengthy, but I hope it is helpful to others struggling with this topic. I've put up [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pd95/6c561bcfbb5edb6e1a972334ae668679) with my working example to copy and explore.

Comment: You've done huge research! Thank you! I was looking for the answer for quite some time. Unfortunately, this only proves my guess that SwiftUI is simply not yet ready for UIManagedDocument or NSPersistentDocument.

Comment: Thank you. This issue has plagued my UIKit based app as well. My app has a ViewController that allows the user to create new documents, and does not require the user to close the currently opened document. When the document is created I populate it with some default data, and I would get this error. Your solution fixed it. As an aside, my model is stored in a swift package. In that case, be sure to use `.module` as the `Bundle`.